# css, js, images are not loading in my rails app in development environments

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In browser console its showing like this:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1"
>   applica...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d602bdfe68ffc63b9f9cc512872aa3cfff046228a0a36e90dd476e8ef54c1b09.js?body=1"
>   jquery_...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1"
>   turboli...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/welcome.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1"
>   welcome...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/jquery.self-c64a74367bda6ef8b860f19e74df08927ca99d2be2ac934e9e92d5fd361e0da4.js?body=1"
>   jquery....?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/welcome.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"
>   welcome...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1"
>   applica...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d602bdfe68ffc63b9f9cc512872aa3cfff046228a0a36e90dd476e8ef54c1b09.js?body=1"
>   jquery_...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1"
>   turboli...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/welcome.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"
>   welcome...?body=1
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1"
>   applica...?body=1

Comment: Can you provide more information? Which version of Rails are you using? I would take a guess that this is your sprockets manifest trying to find files that don't exist and that asset precompilation is needed to reset it: try running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.5 version and my ruby version is 1.9.3p429,

Comment: I run this command before, It's create a assets folder in public folder but same errors are return

Comment: Is it actually trying to load assets from example.com or did you change the logs?

Comment: No I didn't change anything, 
I just run 'rails new myapp' and than run 'rails server'.